# Get Data From Redis in batch RedisTemplate

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am using **RedisTemplate** in my **spring boot application** and I am able to read using singleKey.

```
String valueJson = (String) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(setKey(someId));
```

I have now a List of "someId" like "List someIds" and I want to get the data of all Ids. Of course I can iterate on the list and hit redis with indivisual keys, but I dont want that, instead I want provide the whole list to get the response in one go.

Please help.

Comment: Depending on the underlying data type, there are bulk commands like `MGET`, `HMGET` to read multiple keys (strings) or entries from a hash. Otherwise, like Thomas wrote, use pipelining to issue multiple commands and synchronize at the end.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use pipelining: https://redis.io/topics/pipelining

```
List<Object> results = redisTemplate.executePipelined(
  new RedisCallback<Object>() {
    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
      StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection)connection;
      for(String id:someIds) 
        stringRedisConn.get(id);

    return null;
  }
});
```

Or in Java 8:

```
List<Object> results = redisTemplate.executePipelined((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
    StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = (StringRedisConnection) connection;

    someIds.forEach(id -> {
        stringRedisConn.get(id);
    });

    return null;
});
```

The results List will contain all that you want.

Comment: Worth to not that, at the moment (ver 2.9.0), while trying to execute pipelined with a cluster, Jedis will throw: `UnsupportedOperationException: Pipeline is currently not supported for JedisClusterConnection`.